# How is skill bonus for excavations calculated?

Tags: stellaris

The new Ancient Relics story pack added excavations. Each time your scientist works on an excavation, you have a chance to make progress. There are 3 factors that modify the odds: the difficulty of the excavation site, a "skill level", and the number of clues already gathered at the site via partial successes.

How is the skill level calculated? It's clearly not just the skill level of the scientist involved: I've had level 5 scientists working on sites where I got zero skill bonus and level 2 scientists working on sites where I got a skill bonus of 3.

If this is being messed up by a mod, which file/property is it using so I can look through my mods to figure out which one is causing it?

[image: level 3 scientist receiving 0 skill bonus]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about this? I've never seen a case where the skill level wasn't the scientist's level.

Comment: @Studoku I will take a screenshot when I get home. It's possible that one of my mods is messing with the excavation's ability to check the scientist's level. That would be weird, though, since as far as I can tell the level is working properly for all other purposes.

Comment: It should be skill level and +2 if you have researched a bonus from tech. I suggest to try again on an unmodded client

Answer (score 1):

In the vanilla version of the game the skill bonus is always the level of the scientist.

The skill bonus can be increased trough technology, for example trough interaction with the curators you can get access to special curator tech that will add a flat skill bonus to any excavation project.

Any other (negative or positive) bonus could be added trough mods.